# Unable to capture double click event on wxDataViewListCtrl

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

Hi guys I am trying to learn GUI programming with wxPython on Python 3.X

I am trying to capture double click on wxDataViewListCtrl. For testing I have added a button and a data-view-list and set double-click event handler for both the objects. Shown the same in the script given below

When I double click on button-control I am able to see the print-statement on screen but when I double click on data-view-list the event-handler is not getting executed

None of wxWindow event is working for wxDataViewListCtrl. What am I doing wrong ?

```
import wx
import wx.xrc
import wx.dataview

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        gSizer1 = wx.GridSizer( 2, 1, 0, 0 )

        self.m_button1 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"MyButton", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        gSizer1.Add( self.m_button1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_dataViewListCtrl2 = wx.dataview.DataViewListCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        gSizer1.Add( self.m_dataViewListCtrl2, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( gSizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.m_button1.Bind( wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.button_double_click )
        self.m_dataViewListCtrl2.Bind( wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.listview_double_click )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass    

    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def button_double_click( self, event ):
        print("button_double_click")
        event.Skip()

    def listview_double_click( self, event ):
        print("listview_double_click")
        event.Skip()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame1(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you're not supposed to be able to handle low-level events such as clicks or double clicks from the native controls, but to use control-specific events instead. In this concrete case, you probably want to use `wxEVT_DATAVIEW_ITEM_ACTIVATED` instead.

Comment: then why double-click is working in button which is also a native-control

Comment: "Not guaranteed to work" is not the same as "guaranteed not to work". It's a bad idea to handle double click events for the buttons too, but, yes, in practice you can (currently) get them. This could well change in the future.